# Global Exception Handler WPF

Tags: wpf, exception

I am trying to implement a global exception handler, the problem comes when the following line generates an error it just stops in the debugger.

```
   var list = await _repository.GetAllAsync<ContactView>();

Application.Current.DispatcherUnhandledException +=
            new DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventHandler(MainThreadExceptionHandler);
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException +=
          new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(DomainExceptionHandler);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try hooking into `TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException` as follows:

```
TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException += ( sender, eventArgs ) =>
{
    ...
};
```